# Draw polyline on p:gmap without reloading the map

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-gmap

I am trying to draw a polyline when user clicks on PrimeFaces GMap.

The polyline already draws in GMap, but the map always reloads when a user clicks.

I can prevent GMap from reloading if I use JavaScript to draw a polyline.

**Is there a way to accomplish this without using JavaScript?**

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rcSendPoint" actionListener="#{indexBacking.onPointSelect()}" update="gmap"/>
        <p:gmap id="gmap"
                widgetVar="gmap"
            center="-6.9243586, 107.6202013" 
            zoom="20" type="HYBRID" 
            model="#{indexBacking.model}" 
            style="width:100%;height:400px"
            onPointClick="drawPolyline(event);"/>                          
    </h:form>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        var point = null;            
        function drawPolyline(event) {
            if (point === null) {                       
                rcSendPoint([{name: 'latitude', value: event.latLng.lat()}, {name: 'longitude', value: event.latLng.lng()}]);
            }
        }
    </script>

public void onPointSelect() {          
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    lat = Double.valueOf(params.get("latitude"));
    lng = Double.valueOf(params.get("longitude"));  
    polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    model.addOverlay(polyline);
}
```

Comment: Draw it on the map with the plajn google javascript. In addition send it to the server (via the remoteCommand that you already have) for when a full redraw is needed and just don't update the gmap in the remote command

Comment: So the only way is draw with javascript?

Comment: Well, you cannot **partially** update the model from the server

Comment: oww ic"...thx for your info, so now i can focus on javascript